# Is there a way to fetch users from an instance in Realm Cloud?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am new to Realm and currently trying to fetch all users from an instance in Realm Cloud and show them in a list. I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation, so could you please help with this?

I guess, I should somehow get a reference to the instance and from there fetch those users, but not sure how to do that (if it is the right way, of course).